# Interchnage the children of two divs using a button

Tags: javascript, dom

My document structure is:

```
<div id="mainWindow">
    <div id="subele1"></div>
</div>

<div id="subWindow">
    <div id="subele2"></div>
</div>
```

I want to create a button so that the children subele1 and subele2 are interchanged every time the button is clicked.

Comment: you'll need to use javascript for that - have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

UPD

```js
function handleButtonClicked() {
  const mainElement = document.getElementById('subele1')
  const subElement = document.getElementById('subele2')

  const mainElementValue = mainElement.innerHTML
  mainElement.innerHTML = subElement.innerHTML
  subElement.innerHTML = mainElementValue
}
```

```html
<div id="mainWindow">
  <div id="subele1">main Window!</div>
</div>

<div id="subWindow">
  <div id="subele2">sub Window?</div>
</div>

<button id='main' onclick={handleButtonClicked()}>switch</button>
```

Comment: Actually I want a single button which switches the children every time its clicked.

Comment: Updated code snippet, please take a look